# Windows XP Home Profile not loading

Tags: windows-xp, user-profiles

A friend laptop is not loading his normal windows profile it is creating a temp one. How would I go about getting it to load his profile again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**How to recover the damaged user profile in Windows XP**](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555473)

Comment: I'd also recommend running a chkdisk /r on whatever disk holds your profile in case it's hard disk damage that caused it to become corrupted.