# Windows XP login with broken profile

Tags: windows, boot, user-profiles

About on each third boot I get logged in with a strange profile. I log in as usually, but get some temporary profile, a mixture of my settings and default ones. Of course, it's completely unusable, my Thunderbird, Dropbox, etc., start, but know nothing about me. Fortunately, a reboot helps, but it costs quite a lot of time.

This is not the same problem as in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/31557/windows-xp-home-profile-not-loading), I get no error message, and after reboot everything is fine again.

Somebody's having [a similar problem on Vista](https://superuser.com/questions/37679/windows-vista-login-results-in-clean-profile).

It happend again and in the application event log I've found the following:

#### EventId: 1508

> Windows was unable to load the registry. This is often caused by insufficient memory or insufficient security rights.
>
> DETAIL - The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.  for C:\home\Maaartin\ntuser.dat

#### EventId: 1502

> Windows cannot load the locally stored profile. Possible causes of this error include insufficient security rights or a corrupt local profile. If this problem persists, contact your network administrator.
>
> DETAIL - The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

#### EventId: 1515

> Windows has backed up this user's profile. Windows will automatically try to use the backed up profile the next time this user logs on.
>
> For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.

#### EventId: 1511

> Windows cannot find the local profile and is logging you on with a temporary profile. Changes you make to this profile will be lost when you log off.
>
> For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.

The interesting events seem to be the first two, the others are just consequences. I see no valid reason for this:
- It happend just after bootup.
- My memory is 8GB.
- I've never restricted the security rights for anything.
- I hope the registry don't get corrupted again and again on a daily basis.
- I thought, Windows should be able to get access to its own files.

Comment: Back up your important data and run a chkdsk on the hard drive, it could be failing.

Comment: These are all symptoms and (somewhat misleading) errors that can occur when you boot XP while the system drive is out of space.

Answer (score 1):

It may be a corrupt profile.

I would create another user and then copy all your data into that profile.

You can also go to: C:\Documents and Settings\"USERNAME"\Application Data

and copy all the contents and replace the ones from your corrupted account into the new one.

Although it may be better to start off fresh as there may be something in your Application Data causing the problem in the first place.

Comment: Whatever I copy, I risk copying the culprit too. Starting off fresh is as much work as full reinstall, which I really don't want to do. I'd be happy when Windows refrained from giving me the broken and useless profile altogether. If a reboot is really needed, then it should just do that.