# Directories in "C:/Documents and Settings" directory

Tags: windows, home-directory

There are the following directories there

```
Administrator
Administrator.PIXLA09
All Users
All Users.WINDOWS
Default User
Default User.WINDOWS
LocalService
LocalService.NT AUTHORITY
LocalService.NT AUTHORITY.000
Maaartin
Maaartin.PIXLA09
Maaartin.PIXLA09.000
NetworkService
NetworkService.NT AUTHORITY
NetworkService.NT AUTHORITY.000
```

Why do I need both `Maaartin` and `Maaartin.PIXLA09` (Pixla09 is my computer's name)?

What is `Maaartin.PIXLA09.000` good for?

May it be related to [the problem I reported today](https://superuser.com/questions/266932/windows-xp-login-with-broken-profile)?

Comment: Were your low on disk space? I usually see such a profile folder created when I try to boot Windows XP while my system drive is out of space (<=1MB free). (For some reason Windows thinks that creating a new directory and copying the default profile uses less disk space than just using the existing profile.)

Comment: @Synetech: It's a long time ago... I can't tell anymore. For some reason whenever Windows "thinks" strange things happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would replace your hard drive, back up your important data now. Those are temporary profiles being created because the disk is corrupt and possibly failing

Comment: Isn't it possible that he's on a domain so some of these are just from instances where the controller wasn't responding properly and there were duplicate profiles created?  It's certainly possible that it's a problem with the drive but this sounds a bit alarmist to me.

Comment: @Shinrai: Good point, but I'm sure it's not the cause. `NT AUTHORITY\LocalService` and `NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService` are special accounts, [not controlled by SAM or domains](http://serverfault.com/questions/248439/).

Comment: @grawity - Doh!  You're right, I didn't even look that closely at the account names.  That's weird.  (I still think this sounds a bit alarmist though.)

Comment: Better safe than sorry when it comes to data.

Comment: @Shinrai AFAIK, I am on no domain. I wrote "AFAIK" since I don't know WTF Windows is doing. I installed it myself and set no domain up. @Moab All the most important things are under version control (pushed to a server many times a day), everything gets rsync-ed to an external disk twice a week. What can't be backup are those stupid files locked by Windows (registry stuff or whatever), but when the disk fails, I'll reinstall anyway.

Comment: `chkdsk.exe` indeed reports some errors sometimes, but I've never seen any problem except the useless profiles being served to me occasionally. Maybe the disk has a problem, maybe it's just Windows damaging its own filesystem.